# Upgrading runtime and sdk and packages to .NET 6

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

I was following this tutorial on building an application with `ASP.NET Core API` and `Angular` where I used a laptop that had `.NET 5` installed.

I got a new laptop and after I installed all the latest tools, I am now on `.NET 6` and when I open my app to carry on where I left off, I get the following error when I run `dotnet watch run` in the VS Code terminal in the backend folder:

```
The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '5.0.0' (x64) was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      6.0.5 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=5.0.0&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
```

Here are 2 screenshots showing what I have installed in this app from the time I was using it on my old laptop (now opening it and trying to run it on my new laptop)

[image]

[image]

Is there anyway I can cleanly update everything I need in one go, instead of installing `.NET 5` or `AspNetCore.App version 5.0.0` etc?

Comment: Just correct the `TargetFramework` element's content to `net6.0`.

Comment: Also update the NuGet packages

Comment: @MarioVernari Solved! Thank you. If you put your comment in an answer, I will accept as the correct answer that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just correct the `TargetFramework` element's text content to `net6.0`.

Also update the `NuGet` packages.

Don't mind what's inside the `bin` and `obj` folders, whereas exist. Even better, make sure to `Clean` or `Rebuild` your project.